# como faço post de um objeto que tem outra que tem o próprio objeto

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate, spring, jpa

isso vai ser meio difícil de explicar, mas vou tentar. Estou fazendo um back-end de um gerenciador de pacotes(por enquanto um projeto pessoal) chamado Super Package Manager(preverível chamar de "spm"). O spm terá seu back-end chamado "spm-back" que guardará os pacotes e dois front-ends que irão utilizar-lo: o próprio programa CLI spm(sendo desenvolvido em c++) e um website chamado "spmhub". O spm CLI será usado em uma distro linux independente que será criada depois do spm estiver pronto e completo. Para simplificar o projeto, criei uma uml para mostrar como será as classes.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como é mostrado nessa uml, há duas classes nela: a Repository e a Archive. A classe Repository tem a função de guardar informações sobre o pacote e guardar várias versões dele.
A classe Archive guarda o endereço do arquivo zipado e pré-compilado no próprio servidor ou numa nuvem como Microsoft azure(não pode colocar o arquivo no banco de dados porque seria uma opção cara, a mais barata é quardar o arquivo no servidor ou nuvem e colocar na tabela do banco de dados apenas o local onde o arquivo está armazenado), também guarda o a versão e o status do arquivo(em desenvolvimento, release cadidata ou release).
o código de cada classe fica assim(estou usando lombok para diminuir código sujo):

```java
@Entity @Table(name = "repository_tb") @Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class Repository {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    private String description;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "repository")
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Set<Archive> archives = null;
    
    public Repository(@NonNull String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}

@Entity @Table(name = "archive_tb")
@AllArgsConstructor @Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class Archive {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(unique = true) @JsonIgnore
    private String packagePath;
    
    @ManyToOne @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "repository_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Repository repository;
    
    private String version;
    
    private ArchiveStatus status;
    
    public Archive() {
    }
}
```

Na classe Archive, é usado `@JsonIgnore`: no repository para evitar um looping(archive chamar repository e repository chamar archive infinitamente) e no packagePath para evitar mostrar informações confidenciais sobre o servidor ou nuvem.
Enquanto estava fazendo os controladores REST de cada classe, surgiu uma dúvida sobre o método post: como vou inserir no banco de dados um objeto que chama outro que chama o próprio objeto? Por exemplo quero inserir o navegador firefox para a distro linux ter um navegador, poderia criar o seguinte json para tentar inserir o navegador no banco de dados:

```js
{
    "name": "firefox",
    "description": "mozilla browser",
    "archives": [
        {
            "version": "120.0.1",
            "status": "RELEASE"
        }
    ]
}
```

**esse json representa um repository**
quando eu vou dar um post usando o postman com esse json e um header adcional "Content-Type=application/json", parece que funciona normalmente, vou no console do banco de dados e aparece o seguinte problemana tabela archive_tb:

```
|id|repository_id|package_path|version|status|
|--|-------------|------------|-------|------|
|1 | *null*      |*null*      |120.0.1|3     |
```

tudo bem. O problema é o repository_id que está nulo, isso é contra a regra de cardinalidade citada na uml que um archive **tem que ter** 1 repository. Tive a ideia de colocar `nullable = false` no `@JoinColumn` de repository na classe Archive. Fiz o mesmo post com o mesmo header, só que o hibernate dá throw `org.hibernate.PropertyValueException` dizendo que o repository_id está nulo, esperava que o hibernate automaticamente colocasse o id.
Como posso fazer o post com aquele json que mostrei e o campo `repository_id` não ficar nulo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de alguns dias e ter pesquisado bastante, **achei a solução**.
Quando fazemos o post, o jpa trata em colocar o foreign key no primeiro objeto que a gente especificar, por quê? Porque se o jpa tratasse em colocar o o foreign key tanto nos outros objetos dentro do objeto que a gente quer guardar, vai criar um looping infinito pois um tem o outro e o outro vai chamar o um. Por exemplo:
Se quisermos fazer o post de um Repository com o seguinte json:

```js
{
    "name": "firefox",
    "description": "mozilla browser",
    "archives": [
        {
            "version": "120.0.1",
            "status": "RELEASE"
        }
    ]
}
```

O jpa vai apenas postar o Repository e os Archives dentro do banco de dados sem colocar o foreign key no archive, pois essa não é a função do jpa(ela apenas salva), então nós mesmos devemos especificar o ´´repository´´ daquele Archive dentro do Repository que queremos postar. Mas se a gente fazer isso, devemos especificar o Repository dentro do archive dentro do Repository(sentindo cheiro de looping infinito no json?), então o json seria assim:

```js
{
    "name": "firefox",
    "description": "mozilla browser",
    "archives": [
        {
            "version": "120.0.1",
            "status": "RELEASE",
            "repository": {
                "name": "firefox",
                "description": "mozilla browser",
                "archives": [
                    {
                        "version": "120.0.1",
                        "status": "RELEASE",
                        "repository": {/*infinitamente*/}
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Seria impossível isso né? Pois bem, pensei "se o jpa só boja o foreign key no primeiro objeto, então porque não tratar salvar primeiro o Archive depois o repository?"(em relação ao json), então o troquei o `@JsonIgnore` de lugar nas duas classes, ficando assim o código:

```java
@Entity @Table(name = "repository_tb") @Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class Repository {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    private String description;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "repository")
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)  @JsonIgnore //deve ser aqui
    private Set<Archive> archives = new HashSet<>(); //jamais deixe um Collection nulo, apenas vazio
    
    public Repository(@NonNull String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}

@Entity @Table(name = "archive_tb")
@AllArgsConstructor @Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class Archive {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(unique = true) @JsonIgnore
    private String packagePath;
    
    @ManyToOne //aqui não
    @JoinColumn(name = "repository_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Repository repository;
    
    private String version;
    
    private ArchiveStatus status;
    
    public Archive() {
    }
}
```

Assim, qualquer get que fazer do Repository, o resultado sairia apenas o próprio Repository sem a lista de seus Archives:

```js
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "firefox",
    "description": "mozilla browser"
}
```

e se fazer o mesmo com o archive, o resultado:

```js
{
    "id": 1,
    "repository": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "firefox",
        "description": "mozilla browser"
        /* nada sobre os archives */
    },
    "version": "120.0.1",
    "status": "RELEASE"
}
```

Quando eu fui ver o campo `repository_id` na mesma tabela, ele não estava mais nulo! Perfeito! Era o que eu queria! Mas surgiu outra pergunta "Mas se eu encontrar(no puro código) o repository que quero, os Archives vão estar destro no ArrayList `archives`?", fiz o teste apenas imprimindo na tela o Repository que eu encontrava e o `Set<Archive> archives` estava com os seus Archives! Então achei a solução e ela realmente funciona.
**Lição de hoje:**
Quando estiver montando um relacionamento um para muitos, coloque o `@JsonIgnore` no lado do um, não no lado do muitos.